# SUPEE-10266 HUNK Failed

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-10266

How can I **solve** this **error**:

```
# bash PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-34-33.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Grid/Renderer/Notice.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 108 (offset 12 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/QueueController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 686 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 459 (offset 3 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Data.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 57.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 77.
2 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Serializer/Adapter/PhpCode.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 120 (offset 26 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 155 (offset 26 lines).
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login-simple.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 58 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 46 with fuzz 1 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
checking file app/design/install/default/default/template/install/create_admin.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 66.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
checking file downloader/template/login.phtml
```

It's a Magento 1.9.1.0 CE installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hunk #1 succeeded means some space or line break in the code it automatically detected and succeeded. Don't worry about that.

Download the Magento 1.9.1.0 and Please check any core changes in two file.

```
app/design/install/default/default/template/install/create_admin.phtml
app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Data.php
```

Comment: Please let me know any core changes in these two files

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to solve this.

1. Is your all patches applied in sequence and you didnt change any file manually. Apply patches in order.
2. Check your current magento version and download same fresh version.
   Just put `(ex). app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv` file from downloded version
   Now apply patch again .
3. Before current patch if any other patch has changed this file then download zip file of that patch and replace this file and apply patch again.

Try this it will work.

Comment: I've replaced 'app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv' with the default file, however the patch still can't succeed. Same error. When I look at 'app/etc/applied.patches.list' there is only one patch: 'PATCH_SUPEE-9767'

Comment: @Leslie there are two version of 9767 patch. First apply that both successfully and then try this patch

Comment: I've applied v2, do I still need to patch v1 too?

Comment: @Leslie yes apply v1 and then v2 and then 10266 patch

Comment: still no luck. I've applied both patches but 10266 won't succeed.